# Reading information stored in header array when reading BMP file in c

Tags: c, type-conversion, bmp, bitmapimage, unsigned-char

I am trying to learn image processing using c.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    FILE *streamIn;
    streamIn=fopen("lena512.bmp","r");

    //read imageHeader and colorTable
    unsigned char header[54];//to store the image header
    //unsigned char colorTable[1024];//to store the colorTable,if it exists

    for(int i=0;i<54;i++){
            header[i]=getc(streamIn);
    }
    /*
      width of the image(18th byte)
      height of the image(22nd byte)
      bitDepth of the image(28th byte)
    */
    int width=*(int*)(&header[18]);
    int height=*(int*)(&header[22]);
    int bitDepth=*(int*)(&header[28]);


}
```

I came across the line which i couldn't understand.

```
int width=*(int*)(&header[18]);
```

Why can't we simply do the type casting like `int width=(int)(header[18]);?`

Comment: Because `header` is declared `unsigned char (array of)`. Aside: it's better to use the official Windows headers for this.

Comment: To clarify, `(int)<something>` does not mean treat `<something>` as if it were an `int` reference. Rather it means, _convert_ whatever `<something>` is to `(int)`. In this case `<something>` is `header[18]`, which is an `unsigned char` value. So that will take that one byte value and expand it to `int` size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `*(int*)(&header[18])` and you want to know why `(int)(header[18])` can't be used.

Well, these are completely different expressions.

The first one takes **the address** of `header[18]`, which is an `unsigned char`, so this gives a pointer to such. Casting it to a pointer to `int` and dereferencing it by `*` in the assignment copies a complete `int` starting at that address, reading all necessary bytes.

The second one simply reads the single `unsigned char` in `header[18]` and casts **the value** to an `int`. This will use only the first byte.

---

*Note: Microsoft's header files provide structure definitions of the  BMP header. It's much better to use them. You can for example call `fread()` to read the header.*

Answer (score 2):

> I came across the line which i couldn't understand.
> `int width=*(int*)(&header[18]);`

Neither did the person who wrote it, because this is blatant undefined behavior in several different ways. It gives This gives a misaligned address (on mainstream systems) as well as a strict aliasing violation. [What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)

Those 3 lines at the end are bugs, you cannot write C code like that. The correct way to write this program might be to copy the data into pre-defined structs, provided by the OS API.

Comment: (Unfortunately in case of Windows wingdi.h, the bitmap API is broken by design and relies on the ancient "struct hack". So it cannot be reliably used by standard C compilers...)